# how do I reference fields from sub query?

Tags: soql

```
Map<Id,Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>([Select Id, Subject, (Select CreatedBy.Manager.Email, CreatedBy.Manager.Name From Case_Status_Trackings__r WHERE Case_Status__c = 'Closed' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Case WHERE Id = '500...']);
for (Case case_x : cases.values()) {
    System.debug(case_x.Subject);

}
```

How can I reference the custom/related object's fields inside this loop?
I want to access Case_Status_Trackings__r.CreatedBy.Manager.Email but can't work out what the syntax should be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Map<id,case> cases = new Map<id,case>([select id,Subject,(select CreatedBy.Manager.Email, CreatedBy.Manager.Name From Case_Status_Trackings__r WHERE Case_Status__c = 'Closed' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Case WHERE Id = '500...']);
for(case case_x : cases.values()){
    for(Case_Status_Trackings__c c : case_x.Case_Status_Trackings__r ){
        system.debug('####'+c.createdby.manager.email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the returned Cases, and refer to it's child object via the relantionship field.

```
for (Case case : cases.values()) {
    list<Case_Status_Trackings__c> trackings = case.Case_Status_Trackings__r;
    //Do a loop for the list again
}
```